# no-changed-when lint warning araise in the ansible playbook

Tags: automation, ansible, helm3

I have been creating a role in Ansible and when I run my gitci pipeline, i get a warning message as

> "no-changed-when: Commands should not change things if nothing needs doing"

I have tried to use `changed_when: false` on the task file. When I try to deploy the image build, I get the permission error or status doesn't show properly.
In the example below, I am just copying the files from one directory to another.

Let me know how to use the shell module here.

E.g.

```yaml
- name: Copy the configuration files to the Helm Directory
  shell: "cp {{ files_dir_path }}/*.xml {{ roles_dir_path }}/{{ image.docker_tag }}/files/helm- chart/"
```

Comment: Alternatively, would the `copy` module suffice here?

Comment: No, It would not. The module [copy](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/copy_module.html#ansible-builtin-copy-copy-files-to-remote-locations) does not support wildcard. But [synchronize](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/posix/synchronize_module.html#ansible-posix-synchronize-a-wrapper-around-rsync-to-make-common-tasks-in-your-playbooks-quick-and-easy) would.

Comment: Thank you for the response, My point was to more on how to use changed_when :false option.

Answer (score 0):

I am a little late to the party, but for those, that stumble upon this:
Ansible wants to be idempotent, so it needs to be able to verify if a change is necessary. In your example Ansible has to blindly run a command, without being able to check if that is even necessary. This is what the warning wants to tell you.

You can solve this, by giving Ansible a file, that will be present, only after the command ran. That way Ansible will skip the task the next time around.

```
- name: Copy the configuration files to the Helm Directory
  shell: "cp {{ files_dir_path }}/*.xml {{ roles_dir_path }}/{{ image.docker_tag }}/files/helm- chart/"
  args:
    creates: "{{ roles_dir_path }}/{{ image.docker_tag }}/files/helm- chart/*.xml"
```

See e.g., the [command module documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/command_module.html#parameter-creates) for further reference.